# Read either Double or Int

Tags: haskell

[image]

read function requires type annotation. However I want to make it read int as int , double as double when either int or double is provided. Can we do that?

Thanks.

Comment: [Never post screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), please.

Comment: good question, but not so good presentation (screenshot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) to first attempt parsing it as an `Int`, if that fails you `read` it as a `Double`. (Note the other way around wouldn't work, because integers are also valid doubles.)

```
readDoubleOrInt :: String -> DoubleOrInt
readDoubleOrInt s = case readMaybe s of
   Just i  -> R i
   Nothing -> L $ read s
```

BTW it's actually better not to use `read` at all, but only `readMaybe` / `readsPrec`, and also defining your instance suitable to handle possible failures. The failure-handling version of the above can also nicely be written using [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) combinators:

```
readMaybeDoubleOrInt :: String -> Maybe DoubleOrInt
readMaybeDoubleOrInt s = R<$>readMaybe s <|> L<$>readMaybe s
```